# Can not detect mouse buttons pressed onmousemove?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, chromium

Recording `onmousedown` and `onmouseup` to use in `onmousemove` does not work because `onmouseup` only fires once if the buttons are released outside the window: http://jsfiddle.net/f1nqproy/5/

`event.button` only returns meaningful results in Internet Explorer.

`event.buttons` only exists in Firefox.

So what to do with other browsers?

EDIT:
MouseEvent.buttons has been standardized now, so this problem has been solved:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MouseEvent/buttons

Comment: Have you ever heard of jquery?

Comment: Use a global handler for the mouse click?

Comment: Is the question about mouseup not firing outside of the window, or is it about browser compatibility in `event.button` ?

Comment: @giammin Yes @Johan Isn't `window.onmouseup` global? @Juan Both are broken. Any of those would work to solve my problem of getting the state of mouse buttons.

Comment: Gosh I cannot test this, apple mouse only allows one button down at a time (cannot click left and right together)! :) [consider this before building an interface like that (also trackpad users may not be able)]

Comment: @FrancescoMM Thanks, I was not aware of that. I will consider it.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do something browser agnostic the easiest way is to use [jQuery](http://jquery.com/)

> jQuery is a fast, small, and feature-rich JavaScript library. It makes
>   things like HTML document traversal and manipulation, event handling,
>   animation, and Ajax much simpler with an easy-to-use API that works
>   across a multitude of browsers. With a combination of versatility and
>   extensibility, jQuery has changed the way that millions of people
>   write JavaScript.

You can easly bind to [mouseup](http://api.jquery.com/mouseup/),[mousedown](http://api.jquery.com/mousedown/) event and forget about browser compatibility

```
$( window).mouseup(function(e){
    console.log("mouseup:", e.button);
});
$( window).mousedown(function(e){    
    console.log("mousedown:", e.button);
});
```

-----UPDATE------

IE (as usual)  do another work so you will not get the mouseup event if the pointer is outside the window.

An hack is to use the mouseleave event:

```
//hack for IE
$( window).mouseleave (function(e){    
    console.log("mouseleave");
});
```

[JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/f1nqproy/8/)

Comment: This code has exactly the same problems I described in the first line of my post, which was that this will not work if two buttons are released outside the window. This is also described in the comments you copied and pasted. Also `mouseudown` should be `mousedown` and on `mouseup` the state of `buttonDown` is supposed to be `false`, not `true`.

Comment: @JohnWayne it cant work on IE becouse IE does not support it. The best bet is to use jquery and the hack i wrote

Comment: It is quite easy to get the mouse button states on mouse move events in Internet Explorer. Those are stored in `window.event.button` as the first, second or third bit. Same with Firefox and `event.buttons`. Also `mouseleave` is something entirely different than `mouseup`. Imagine a first person shooter where it would be deadly to have to manually recenter the mouse to turn further.

Comment: @JohnWayne I agree with you but due to ie not supporting it you don't have choice. Anyway I said that you should use mousedown and mouseup. in ie you should also consider mouseleave

Answer (score 0):

May be, the problem is that events `onmouseup` are triggered simultaneously by browser. Every time it checks, whether event triggered at the moment when mouse cursor is on the element, to which event was bound. 
So, in your case first event triggers (don't know why), while the second doesn't work - it is correct behavior - instead mouseleave event triggered.

Try to catch mouseleave:

```
var buttonDown = [false, false, false];

$( window).on('mouseup mouseleave', function(e){
    buttonDown[e.button] = true;
    console.log("Buttons up:", buttonDown);
    buttonDown = [false, false, false];
});

$( window).on('mousedown', function(e){
    buttonDown[e.button] = true;
    console.log("Buttons down:", buttonDown);
    buttonDown = [false, false, false];
});
```

Comment: `mouseleave` is triggered anyway, no matter if the mouse button is actually released or not. For example you can press mouse buttons, move the mouse outside of the window, get a mouse leave event, enter the window again, release the buttons and get additional mouseup events. Also mouseleave events are not a good replacement for mouseup events, especially for games where you have to aim at targets.